# Remove option for dual SIM in Sony Xperia C3 Dual

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, dual-sim, sony-xperia-c3-dual

My Sony Xperia C3 Dual phone (which has dual SIM slots) has now updated to Lollipop. I never use the second SIM slot, so is there a way to disable or remove the option because in lock-screen mode it gives me the notification about no service on SIM 2 slot?

Answer (score 0):

On Mediatek devices, [Gravitybox](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox) works well to hide the said SIM card notification. However, if this app does not work for your Qualcomm device, then [use](http://www.chinaphonearena.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=3084) an alternative app named [NotifyClean](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.defim.apk.notifyclean&hl=en) which can selectively hide notifications including the said one.

See if it helps.

Note:- Device needs to be rooted and [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) installed.

---

### About Gravitybox

> GravityBox is a module which primary goal is to provide the users of AOSP devices
> with a tweak box to turn their vanilla AOSP ROM into custom ROM packed with additional features and tweaks
> without need to flash anything. Most of the preferences can be changed on-the-fly without rebooting.

### About NotifyClean

> You could configure which apps are allowed to create notifications in the top left area, the notification area. If an app creates a notification it will be collected and added to the list.
> You could deny *all* notifications of an app or only *specific* messages - if it's not a customized notification. So I used it to hide "waiting for connection", but not "you are connected".

Comment: Lollipop also allows to disable notifications natively; but in your case I assume all **Android system** notifications will default as hidden if you try to hide any of them.

Comment: Do not try to install xposed framework on Sony dualC3 d2502 lollipop 5.x.x it will be bricked...